# How to change the value of a python variable from a .kv file

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I am new fairly new to python and have just started using the kivy library. I am trying to change the value of a variable in the .py file when a button from the .kv file is pressed. I am unsure how to instigate this.

The code I currently have is:
python file:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

class experienceScreen(Widget):
    pass   
experience=""

class workoutApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return experienceScreen()
workoutApp().run()

def beginnerpressed(self, instance):
    experience==1


if experience == 1:
    print("test code works.")
if experience == 2:
    print("test code works.")
if experience == 3:
    print("test code works.")
```

kivy file:

```
#: kivy 2.1.0

<experienceScreen>:
   FloatLayout:
      pos:0,0
      size: root.width, root.height
      Label:
         text: "What level of gym go-er are you?"
         pos_hint: {'x':.4,'y':.85}
         size_hint:0.2,0.1
      Button:
         text: "Beginner"
         pos_hint: {'x':.25,'y':.6}
         size_hint:0.5,0.1
         on_press: experience=1
      Button:
         text: "Intermediate"
         pos_hint: {'x':.25,'y':.4}
         size_hint:0.5,0.1
         on_press: experience=2
      Button:
         text: "Advanced"
         pos_hint: {'x':.25,'y':.2}
         size_hint:0.5,0.1
         on_press: experience=3
```

I had expected that when I pressed any of the buttons that the "test code works" text would display in the console. However, this is not the case. I expect this is because variables are assigned differently within the .kv file.

Answer (score 0):

The on_press item needs to be connected to a method (function) in your code.  One can use root.something to reach the widget or app.something to reach a method in the app object.

Kivy file

```
<experienceScreen>:
   FloatLayout:
      pos:0,0
      size: root.width, root.height
      Label:
         text: 'What level of gym go-er are you?'
         pos_hint: {'x':.4,'y':.85}
         size_hint:0.2,0.1
      Button:
         text: 'Beginner'
         pos_hint: {'x':.25,'y':.6}
         size_hint:0.5,0.1
         on_press: root.beginnerpressed(1)
      Button:
         text: 'Intermediate'
         pos_hint: {'x':.25,'y':.4}
         size_hint:0.5,0.1
         on_press: root.beginnerpressed(2)
      Button:
         text: 'Advanced'
         pos_hint: {'x':.25,'y':.2}
         size_hint:0.5,0.1
         on_press: root.beginnerpressed(3)
```

python

```
class experienceScreen(Widget):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.experience = 0

    def beginnerpressed(self, experience: int):
        self.experience = experience
        print(f"test code works. {self.experience}")


class workoutApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return experienceScreen()

workoutApp().run()
```